# Evitar ingresar datos duplicados en una tabla de Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger, insert

quisiera saber como crear un Trigger en **Oracle** que evite datos los datos duplicados en una tabla.
Para iniciar tengo mi tabla temporal:

```
CREATE TABLE temporal(
Nombre varchar(50),
Tipo varchar(50),
Pais varchar(50)
)
```

Que al insertarle datos queda de la siguiente manera

```
----------------------------------
Nombre     |  Tipo      | Pais
----------------------------------
User 1        2           USA
User 2        2           FRANCIA
User 3        1           ALEMANIA
User 4        2           FRANCIA
User 5        1           USA
```

Luego tengo una tabla llamada Pais

```
CREATE TABLE PAIS(idpais int,nombre varchar(50))
```

Lo que quiero es que al momento de insertar en la tabla temporal automaticamente inserte en la tabla Pais los datos del campo pais de esa tabla pero sin ingresar nombres repetidos ya que el **idpais** ya me funciona como autonumerico

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertpais
AFTER INSERT ON temporal
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Pais(nombre) VALUES(:new.Pais)
END
```

Este trigger me funciona pero insertaria dos veces el valor de **FRANCIA** y **USA** a la tabla Pais asi que esa es la parte que quisiera resolver

```
-------------------------
idpais      |   nombre
------------------------
   1              USA
   2             FRANCIA
   3             ALEMANIA
   4             FRANCIA
   5              USA
```

Y yo quisiera

```
-------------------------
idpais      |   nombre
------------------------
   1              USA
   2             FRANCIA
   3             ALEMANIA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla, es usando una clausula `INSERT ... SELECT ..` y en el `SELECT` traer solo las filas de `temporal` cuyos países no se encuentren en `PAIS`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertpais
AFTER INSERT ON temporal
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PAIS(nombre)
SELECT  DISTINCT Pais
    FROM temporal
    WHERE Pais NOT IN (SELECT nombre FROM PAIS);
END;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es exacto lo que necesitaba